# WebSphere EJB timers

Tags: timer, ejb, websphere, websphere-8

We have an application that is currently migrated to  WebSphere 8.5 from WebSphere 6. The application uses EJB annotations and EJB timers. The timers are set to execute every 5 minutes. This feature was working for years without any problems on WebSphere 6. After migrating to WebSphere 8.5 the EJB timers are indefinitely getting triggered every millisecond as supposed to trigger every 5 minutes(a predefined value). Can anybody please help me find the root cause for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same database tables before and after the migration, such that pre-existing timer tasks remain scheduled, and there was a period of time during which they were unable to run, the behavior you describe could be due to catching up on missed executions.

If this is is the case, try querying the table ([documented here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/scheduler/ref/rsch_tabledef.html)) for the NEXTFIRETIME.  If the number of milliseconds represented by this value is for a date in the past, then you can expect to be running missed executions.  One option would be letting it run and allowing it to catch up to the current time.  Otherwise, you could cancel and reschedule the timer tasks.

Comment: We are using the same tables before and after the migration. I queried the NEXTFIRETIME and the date time is in future with a difference of 5 minutes(configured) with the current time.

Comment: Given that you have confirmed that it isn't performing catch-up executions and is actually scheduled for the future, I would recommend opening a case with IBM support.